# Variable doesn't exist outside of the function?

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

you're going to see Wordpress Widget code (a bit modified taken from Akismet).

The problem is $title; variable works fine only in one function and globals etc. doesn't seem to help here.

What's wrong?

```
 function myWidget_control() {
        $options = $newoptions = get_option('myWidget');

        if ( isset( $_POST['myWidget-submit'] ) && $_POST["myWidget-submit"] ) {
            $newoptions['title'] = strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST["myWidget-title"]));
            if ( empty($newoptions['title']) ) $newoptions['title'] = __('Spam Blocked');
        }

        if ( $options != $newoptions ) {
            $options = $newoptions;
            update_option('myWidget', $options);
        }

        $title = htmlspecialchars($options['title'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>

                <p><label for="myWidget-title"><?php _e('Title:');  ?><input style="width: 250px;" id="myWidget-title" name="myWidget-title" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" /></label></p>
                <input type="hidden" id="myWidget-submit" name="myWidget-submit" value="1" />

<?php 
}
function myWidget()
{

   echo $title; /* shows nothing but works perfectly 8 lines above! */
   echo $options['title']; /* shows nothing once again */
}
```

Comment: Works as expected - you are not declaring any globals. See [PHP: Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: But when I declare it doesn't change anything. I declare global $title; in first function, second, in both and nothing happens.

Comment: The global scope is outside of any functions or classes; it doesn't include every variable from everywhere. The keyword "global" doesn't "declare" a variable as global. It merely makes the already-global variable available to the function; a variable defined inside a function is not in the global scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$title is defined within the scope of the myWidget_control() function, so is available only there.

If you need it to be available in myWidget() it must be created/retrieved there too, I would suggest calling get_option('myWidget') again to retrieve it.

```
function myWidget() {
   $options = get_option('myWidget');
   $title = htmlspecialchars($options['title'], ENT_QUOTES);

   echo $title;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Only this solution works. Global ones - no. Can you explain why Globals doesn't? Because it was inside of an array?

Comment: @fomicz, the `global` keyword allows access to variables that are in the global scope (it doesn't in any way *put* variables into global scope). `$options` was not defined in global scope but, rather, function scope. Therefore, the `global` keyword has no effect on it.

Comment: @fomicz Globals could work, but the initial declaration of the variable would have to be at a level (scope) above all the other uses.  ie. you would need to declare $title outside of the functions, and use 'global $title;' inside each function that wished to access it.  Globals are generally frown upon as there is usually a better way to handle the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Those variables are defined within the function itself and thus cannot be accessed outside of those functions unless you tell them to.  Give globalling them a try...

```
function myWidget_control() {
     global $title, $options;
     [yourcode]
}
function myWidget() {
     global $title, $options;

   echo $title;
   echo $options['title'];
```

}

You might not need to global them within both functions, but I think you do.

Comment: Doesn't work, in fact, it totally destroys the whole widget. OMG I used to love but now just HATE Wordpress.

Comment: Given that the value is being retrieved in the correct manner in the first function, using globals would be unnecessary in the second.

Answer (score 0):

The scope is limited to where the variable is defined; in this case the `myWidget_control()` method. See [PHP.NET: variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)